# "GetBy" Methods in Web API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

We are using .NET Core to build a Web API. We need to support "GetBy" functionality, e.g. GetByName, GetByType, etc. but the issue we are running into is how to depict this through routes in a Restful way as well as the method overloading not properly working with how we think the routes should be. We are using MongoDB so our IDs are strings.

I'm assuming our routes should be something like this:

```
/api/templates?id=1
/api/templates?name=ScienceProject
/api/templates?type=Project
```

and the issue is that all our methods in our controller have a single string parameter and isn't properly mapped. Should the routes me different or is there a way to properly map these routes to the proper method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the parameters are mutually exclusive, i.e. you only search by name or type but not by name and type, then you can have the parameter be a part of the path instead of the query-params.

Example

```
[Route("templates")]
public class TemplatesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("byname/{name}")]
    public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
    {
        return Ok("ByName");
    }

    [HttpGet("bytype/{type}")]
    public IActionResult GetByType(string type)
    {
        return Ok("ByType");
    }
}
```

This example would lead to routes like:

```
/api/templates/byname/ScienceProject
/api/templates/bytype/Project
```

If there parameters are not mutually eclusive then you should do it like suggested in the [answer by Fabian H.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46691211/762588)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a TemplatesController with a single get method, that can take all the arguments.

```
[Route("api/templates")]
public class TemplatesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(int? id = null, string name = null, string type = null)
    {
        // now handle you db stuff, you can check if your id, name, type is null and handle the query accordingly
        return Ok(queryResult);
    }
}
```